# Polytope(Polyhedron) library compatible with Eigen library

Tags: c++, static-libraries, polygon, eigen

Is there any Polyhedron(Polytope) library which is compatible with *C++ Eigen Library*? I'm actually looking for a polyhedron library in C++ **like in SAGE of Python**. However, if it can be used with Eigen library, it really serves me in good stead. For instance, I'd like to pass `MatrixXf a` to a function of the Polyhedron(Polytope) library, something similar stuff, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[The Parma Polyhedra Library](http://bugseng.com/products/ppl/) in C++ & [Polylib](http://www.irisa.fr/polylib/) in C